# golang printing even and odd by Scanf

Tags: go, scanf

```
package main 
import "fmt"
func main(){
  fmt.Println("Enter a number: ")
  var i int32
  fmt.Scanf("f",%i)
  output := i*1
  if output%2 == 0{
    fmt.Print("even")
}else {
  fmt.Println("odd")
}
}
```

This is my current code. I am trying to print even and odd number based on using the Scanf but this only print out 'Even'.

Comment: change `fmt.Scanf("f",%i)` to `fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)`

Comment: Thank you Mark, that also worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fmt.Scanf` ([docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf)) takes a format string as the first argument.  You are providing `"f"` which is invalid.  If you read and reacted to the error returned then you would see the error "input does not match format".  This is a working example doing what I believe you originally intended:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Enter a number: ")
    var i int32
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        // maybe a good time to exit
    }
    if i%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Print("even")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("odd")
    }
}
```

The reason you were always getting "even" is because `i` was always equal to 0, and zero is even.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still trying to understand this part.

_, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
  // maybe a good time to exit
 }

Why does it have to be printed before plug it into 'if function'?

Comment: Replace `"%d"` with `"f"` like you had before and try running it again to see what that does.

Comment: "bad verb for %f for integer" is a message, I'm slowly getting there! Thank you

Comment: `if i % 2` is readable but expensive in massive calculation, just do `if i & 1 == 1` is more efficient to check odd integer number ...